# Table view with checkmark

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi, Iam new to iPhone apps. I have a problem with tableview. Here  I want to add checkmark when I click on the cell, it's working fine. But whenever I click on another cell then the before cell should not show the checkmark.Thanx in advance.

Comment: can you show some snap or explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an example project for this a while ago [ExclusiveCheckedTableView](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/ExclusiveCheckedTableView.zip)

Answer (score 0):

A cell's accessory type is set by the **UITableViewDataSource** protocol. This code snippet toggles the cell's accessory type between 'none' and 'checkmark':

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"checkableTableViewCell";
    OEListTableViewCell *cell = (OEListTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[OEListTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryNone : UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```